# toggle state in react works fine but the check in my function is not correct

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have some funky stuff going on with my code. My `toggleChecked()` is supposed to select all rooms when `isChecked: true` meaning when checkbox is checked in UI select all rooms.

Its working, it selects all rooms when the `isChecked is true` however in `toggleCheck()` my check is if `this.state.isCheck === false` if so then select all rooms. What this check should be is `this.state.isCheck === true`. When I have this `true` check it doesn't work as expected. For i.e. when the check box in unchecked thats when all rooms get selected. But when the check is for `false` then it works as expected.

````
```
   if(this.state.isChecked === false){
        const roomOrder = //this variable has all the rooms in an array;
        this.setState({selectedRooms: roomOrder}); 
    }else{
        this.setState({selectedRooms : []}); 
    }```
````

````
export default class Room extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
               isChecked: false
            };

            this.toggleChecked = this.toggleChecked.bind(this);
        }

    toggleChecked() {
        this.setState( ({ isChecked: !this.state.isChecked }));

        if(this.state.isChecked === false){

            const roomOrder = //this variable has all the rooms in an array;
            this.setState({selectedRooms: roomOrder}); 

        }else{
            this.setState({selectedRooms : []}); 
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
           <Modal.Footer>
                <Checkbox onChange={this.toggleChecked}> Select All Rooms </Checkbox>
           <Modal.Footer> 
      )
     }```
````

Comment: `this.setState()` is not synchronous because of how react is optimizing UI updates, so it does not guarantee the state is already updated when you are comparing `this.state.isChecked`. Try using callback like `this.setState(..., () => {   your code })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot check for setState change after state is changed, try the callback way, this should work in your case.

You could go through the documentation for more details.

```
 toggleChecked() {
        this.setState({ isChecked: !this.state.isChecked }, ()=>{
            if(this.state.isChecked === false){
            const roomOrder = //this variable has all the rooms in an array;
            this.setState({selectedRooms: roomOrder}); 
        }else{
            this.setState({selectedRooms : []}); 
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Hi @AkhilAravinf thanks this worked for me, what exactly is happening here, I'd like to understand ?

Comment: The callback is excecuted after the setState is completed, as is an async function, so the arrow function after the setState has the updated value.

Comment: @Jose sorry I was offsite for  few days, Hope [@ricardo] has given a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
toggleChecked() {
   if(!this.state.isChecked){
     const roomOrder = //this variable has all the rooms in an array;
     this.setState({selectedRooms: roomOrder, isChecked: !this.state.isChecked}); 
   }else{
     this.setState({selectedRooms : [], isChecked: !this.state.isChecked}); 
   }
}
```